# Dropdown with slideDown with changing menu title on click

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a dropdown menu that slides down on hover, and then slides back up. The title of the dropdown is the active list item. The `<li>` becomes active when a user clicks and the `<li>` receives class `active-markup-style` which has `display:block`. It works for the most part, except that when the user clicks on the list item, it immediately removes the `active-markup-style` class from the previously active `<li>`, returning that `<li>` to `display:none`. How can I get around this so that the previously active `<li>` stays active until the dropdown closes?

```js
$('#dropdown-content').hover(
 function(){
        $(this).children().slideDown(200);
   },
    function(){
        $(this).children().slideUp(0);

});

$('.markup-btn').click(function () {
    $(this).addClass('active-markup-style');
    $('.markup-btn').not($(this)).removeClass('active-markup-style');
    });
```

```css
ul#dropdown-content {
    display:inline-block;
    }

.markup-btn {
    display:none;
    }

li.active-markup-style {
    display:block !important;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="dropdown-content">
      <li id="markup1" class="markup-btn active-markup-style">Original</li>
      <li id="markup2" class="markup-btn">Markup</li>
      <li id="markup3" class="markup-btn">Final</li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: $('.markup-btn').not($(this)).removeClass('active-markup-style'); try removing this line of codes. because its removing the class,

Comment: That code is both good and bad. It makes it so the clicked `<li>` is shown when the dropdown closes, but yeah, it also gets rid of the class of the last active one.

Comment: yeah because they have the same class name. .

Comment: have you tried removing the lines I have told you ?

Comment: I did, but it didn't work how I needed it to.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I created another class, that is assigned on click as a reference. Then I used a callback function to assign the active class following `slideUp`

```
$('#dropdown-content').hover(
     function(){
            $(this).children().slideDown(200);
       },
        function(){
            $(this).children().slideUp(0, function() {
                $('.markup-btn').removeClass('active-markup-style-show');
                $('li.active-markup-style').addClass('active-markup-style-show');
                });

    });

$('.markup-btn').click(function () {
    $(this).addClass('active-markup-style');
    $('.markup-btn').not($(this)).removeClass('active-markup-style');
    });
```